# .jar file path from jnlp file

Tags: java, jnlp

Please I want quick help downloading jar files from jnlp file , the ones that are downloaded in cache are named randomly and not as per jnlp file names i.e. it has names like 345546acb-1da47a98-1_2_3_4 rather than jarOne.jar, please either with the correct URL that I need to use for downloading the jars for below code or how should have get correct names for jar files downloaded in cache folder. I can see all correct jar names in java console but cannot download from there

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" codebase="http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:XXXXX/abc/def/" href="ghk.jnlp"> 
       <information>        
       <title>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</title>  
       <vendor>random </vendor>      
       <offline-allowed/>               
       <icon href="random.jpg"/>   
       </information>    
       <resources>           
       <jar href="JarOne.jar"  version="1_2_3_4"/>
```

Comment: thanks for quick attention, I tried but it returns resource not found. Might be something related to version attribute

Comment: this XML is jnlp file only

Comment: yeh, not sure, for all resources I am getting same 404, not sure how to append version attribute in request URI, might try that

Comment: yes might be something like that is missing, URLs  in cache views are same as you first mentioned codebase/href, but gives 404, is there any way I can use jars already downloaded jars in cache, only issue is they are not named correctly but somehow console is able to identify then correctly, but I cannot map them to copy those jars in load runner path

Answer (score 1):

Resolved now,
needed to append `?version-id=1_2_3_4`